# SQL Server query error for conversiontype

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting an error in SQL Server for the code.

SQL code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
    HEADER.PONUMBER, 
    SName,
    CompanyName
FROM 
    HEADER 
INNER JOIN 
    PDetails  ON HEADER.PONUMBER = PDetails.PoNumber 
INNER JOIN 
    FAN_P ON PDetails.PurchaseOrderID = FAN_P.PurchaseOrderID
```

Error message:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'PO321211' to data type int.

Could you please me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is clear. You are trying to compare and `INT` column to a `VARCHAR` column. To alleviate this, you can cast or convert your comparisons to varchar. I did them all since I don't know which is causing the error... but it's the column with `PO321211` in it :)

```
SELECT  DISTINCT  HEADER.PONUMBER, 
                  SName,
                  CompanyName
FROM HEADER INNER JOIN PDetails 
ON CAST(HEADER.PONUMBER AS VARCHAR(128)) = CAST(PDetails.PoNumber AS VARCHAR(128))
INNER JOIN FAN_P ON CAST(PDetails.PurchaseOrderID AS VARCHAR(128)) = CAST(FAN_P.PurchaseOrderID AS VARCHAR(128))
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check data type of

```
HEADER.PONUMBER
Details.PoNumber
```

and

```
PDetails.PurchaseOrderID
FAN_P.PurchaseOrderID
```

Like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT HEADER.PONUMBER,SName,CompanyName
           FROM HEADER
     INNER JOIN PDetails 
             ON HEADER.PONUMBER = concat(PDetails.PoNumber, '') 
     INNER JOIN FAN_P 
             ON PDetails.PurchaseOrderID = FAN_P.PurchaseOrderID
```

Or

```
SELECT DISTINCT HEADER.PONUMBER, SName, CompanyName 
           FROM HEADER
     INNER JOIN PDetails 
             ON HEADER.PONUMBER = concat('PO',PDetails.PoNumber) 
     INNER JOIN FAN_P 
             ON PDetails.PurchaseOrderID = FAN_P.PurchaseOrderID
```

Comment: Hi Christian, HEADER.PONUMBER is VARCHAR2 AND DETAILS.PONUMBER is INT.

Comment: Try to use HEADER.PONUMBER = concat(PDetails.PoNumber, '') in the join

Comment: Could you elaborate on it please ? Thanks

Comment: Like this

SELECT  DISTINCT  HEADER.PONUMBER, 
                  SName,
                  CompanyName
FROM HEADER INNER JOIN PDetails 
ON HEADER.PONUMBER = concat(PDetails.PoNumber, '') 
INNER JOIN FAN_P ON PDetails.PurchaseOrderID = FAN_P.PurchaseOrderID

check the edited answer

Comment: This isnt working,                                                                                 SELECT DISTINCT HEADER.PONUMBER, SName, CompanyName FROM HEADER INNER JOIN PDetails ON HEADER.PONUMBER = concat("PO",PDetails.PoNumber') INNER JOIN FAN_P ON PDetails.PurchaseOrderID = FAN_P.PurchaseOrderID

Comment: Check this line

Your line....HEADER.PONUMBER = concat("PO",PDetails.PoNumber')

My line HEADER.PONUMBER= concat(PDetails.PoNumber, '')

Reread my first answer. Ahi add the full query

Comment: Maybe you need this

SELECT DISTINCT HEADER.PONUMBER, SName, CompanyName FROM HEADER INNER JOIN PDetails ON HEADER.PONUMBER = concat('PO',PDetails.PoNumber) INNER JOIN FAN_P ON PDetails.PurchaseOrderID = FAN_P.PurchaseOrderID